# iMac G4 fails to boot - dissolve to white screen

Tags: imac, powerpc

Anyone seen this before?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGbHLSrdS5Q

[image]

Basically, I replaced the hard drive as the previous one had started throwing errors, and making knocking noises.  Is the white screen like that indicative of a video card error?  Did I crimp the video cord upon reinstalling it?  Any ideas?

I've reset pram (2 chimes), and attempted to reset nvram (cmd-opt-n-v), but I'm not sure the nvram reset takes.

Comment: Can you boot to recovery? [Hardware test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201257)?

Comment: Recovery mode and hardware test options all do this same thing.

Comment: Even hardware test? And what about [verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201573)?

Comment: *Did I crimp the video cord upon reinstalling it? Any ideas?*  You have to open it back up and check - only you can determine that.

Comment: @allan yes I get that. I’ve opened a number of times and checked/reseated components etc. was hoping someone who repairs these units may have seen this symptom before since the video cord is very hard to replace.

Comment: @JBis thanks for the suggestions. No luck on either of those two ideas. Interestingly my key combination startups do seem to have an effect as I can hear attempts to boot off the CD etc. I just always get the same result on the screen in all cases. :/

Comment: @dpb Do you have any other mac near you?

Comment: @JBis I have a couple more but they are much newer models. Nothing ancient like this. :)

Comment: @dpb Can you try [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25318?locale=en_AU) not sure if it will work with your models?

Comment: @dpb Lastly, can you try plugging it into an external monitor?

Comment: Chances are, it's your video card.

Comment: No luck on the target disk mode.  My current macs don't even have firewire.  I'm thinking my next step would be to replace the video card, which unfortunately is part of the logic board.  Thanks for the suggestion all, time to hit ebay and see if I can pick up something cheap.